# Nested generic types in Map - ts

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

How can we specify nested generic types in map for following scenario:

```
export interface Part0 <T = number> {
    partsInLib : T;

}

export interface Part1 <T = string> {
    desc : T;

}

export interface MainPart <T = number, T1 = string> {
    component?: Part0 <T>;
    anotherComponent?: Part1 <T1>;
    count: number;
}


let mapObj : Map<string, MainPart<T = number, T1 = string>>; // this gives error

mapObj = new Map<string, MainPart>();


function processMainPart<T = number, T2=string>(incomingPart1 : Part1<T2>){ 

    let mp : MainPart<T,T2> = 
              { anotherComponent: incomingPart1, count: 0 } 

    mapObj.set( "a1", mp); 

}
```

What is correct way of defining map nested types here.

Comment: `let mapObj : Map<string, MainPart<number,string>>;`

Comment: Thanks, but with this approach following function have error:

```
function processMainPart<T = number, T2=string>(incomingPart1 : Part1<T2>){

 let mp : MainPart<T,T2> = {
  anotherComponent: incomingPart1,
  count: 0
 }

 mapObj.set( "a1", mp);
}
```

have error:

Argument of type 'MainPart<T, T2>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MainPart<number, string>'.
  Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'number'.

at mapObj.set( "a1", mp);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please consider [edit] the code here to make a [mre] that clearly spells out the problem you're running into and shows use cases so that others can help.  If you need the `processMainPart()` function from your comment to work a certain way, it should be part of the question.  It should be something people can drop into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w2KXbN) to see what's going on.